# SQL Select to SSIS Derived Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I have this Select Query.

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE('000010A', '0', ' ')),' ', '0')

'000010A'= Customer_And_Partner_Account_Nr
```

I would want to Create a New column while loading data through SSIS in SQL table.

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE('000010A', '0', ' ')),' ', '0')
```

Please help me on the expression to create a Derived Column in SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Script Component rather than Derived Column?

In script component, you could overload the `ProcessInputRow` event and use the `TrimStart("0"c)` method on the column to get rid of leading zeroes.

It should also improve the performance of the flow because (1) it only requires single operation and (2) it only scans a portion of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same expression but replace single quotes with double quotes:

```
REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE([Customer_And_Partner_Account_Nr], "0", " ")," ", "0")
```